# How do I use objects in the ion-input field

Tags: ionic-framework

I have an ion-input field that has to use objects or nulls form the backend service and return the objects or nulls.  I am able to do this but the input field will display [object Object] as expected.

object

```
{ContactRelationID: 345678, Name: Thomas}
```

ion-input shows [object Object]

```
<ion-input name=“test”  [(ngModel)]="ContractorInput" readonly></ion-input>
```

ion-input shows Thomas with object but fails with null

```
<ion-input name=“test”  [(ngModel)]="ContractorInput.Name" readonly></ion-input>
```

Is there anyway to suppress the null error when trying to bind to the [(ngModel)]="ContractorInput.Name" or view just view Thomas in the input and not [object Object]

Comment: What's the *format* are you expecting to see in the ion-input? Also, since it's *readonly* could it helps to render the result in just text instead of an input? Wanting to know a bit more about your goal before trying a solution. ;)

Comment: Basically I can hide the input if required as the user does not need to see the object.  But i would like the user to see the name Thomas.  I am presently trying ion-selectable but I think it is not an optimum solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's really no need for two-way binding on an input for data that is "readonly". Forget `[(ngModel)]` and just assign the value directly. Use the `?.` optional chaining operator so that if the value is null it will just be an empty input.

```html
<ion-input name="test" value="{{ContractorInput?.Name}}" readonly></ion-input>
```

Comment: Added `?.` optional chaining operator. Should be fine now. See edit above.